# How to display the minibuffer above candidates in helm

Tags: helm, window

I am looking for configuration that displays the minibuffer in which to type input above matching candidates in a helm buffer.
I went through each helm variable and the closest named variable was `helm-display-source-at-screen-top` but it doesn't do what I am looking for.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FWIW, there is a *near comprehensive* `helm` manual in [Helm Manuals](https://rnchzn.github.io/helm/doc/)**.  I happened to discover this URL accidentally while searching through the issues page of `helm`.

---

Try

[`helm-exchange-minibuffer-and-header-line` which is bound to `C-c %`](https://rnchzn.github.io/helm/doc/helm.html#index-helm_002dexchange_002dminibuffer_002dand_002dheader_002dline-_0028helm_002dmap_0029).  That command temporarily toggles the user option [`helm-echo-input-in-header-line`](https://rnchzn.github.io/helm/doc/helm.html#index-helm_002decho_002dinput_002din_002dheader_002dline)

[image: helm-exchange-minibuffer-and-header-line]

Answer (score 0):

No, Emacs is somewhat inflexible in this regard. See other questions such as [is it possible to move the emacs minibuffer to the top of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050011/is-it-possible-to-move-the-emacs-minibuffer-to-the-top-of-the-screen). Pretty much all you can do is move the minibuffer to its own frame, and then position that frame and other frames how you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `(setq helm-echo-input-in-header-line t)`.